# When do the parentheses get used in EBNF?

Tags: bnf

If you have grammar like this:

```
<assign> → <id> = <expr> 
<id> → A | B | C 
<expr> → <expr> + <term> 
         |  <term> 
<term> → <term> * <factor> 
         |  <factor> 
<factor> → ( <expr> ) 
          | <id>
```

And then the sentence A = B + C * A, you get this leftmost derivation:

```
<assign> => <id> = <expr> 
         => A = <expr> 
         => A = <expr> + <term> 
         => A = <term> + <term> 
         => A = <factor> + <term> 
         => A = <id> + <term> 
         => A = B + <term> 
         => A = B + <term> * <factor> 
         => A = B + <factor> * <factor> 
         => A = B + <id> * <factor> 
         => A = B + C * <factor> 
         => A = B + C * <id> 
         => A = B + C * A
```

But what about A = B + ( C * A )?

Answer (score 2):

> > A = B + ( C * A )?

First five steps, same as above, then...

```
     => A = B + <term>  
     => A = B + <factor>    
     => A = B + ( <expr>) 
     => A = B + ( <term> )  
     => A = B + ( <term> * <factor> ) 
     => A = B + ( <factor> * <factor> ) 
     => A = B + ( <id> * <id> ) 
     => A = B + (  C   *   A  )
```

Comment: Nominally you collapse two steps into one with the penultimate rule, but the result is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

`( C * A )` doesn't need a paren, because * has greater priority. One case where you'd see it is in `A = B * ( C + B )`.

You don't see it in the last two lines because `<factor>` is going to eval to be either a `<term> + <term>` or an `<id>`. In this case there's no + so it has to be an `<id>`.